# How to put if/else statements in list comprehension along with multiple supporting expressions

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension, generator-expression

How can i convert this kind of loops into list comprehension.

```
for x in email_data:
    data = Apply_Filters(x[0])
    if len(data.split()) > 1:
        email_data2.append(tuple([x[1], data]))
```

So far my search got me to the comprehensions with only if else statements without performing any other functions like .

```
[y if y not in b else other_value for y in a]
```

But i first have to apply a function to a looping variable and then have to use conditional structure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: a list comprehension for the `email_data2` or the `temp` lists?

Comment: You can't create two lists with one list comprehension directly.

Comment: and as a sidenote, there is no `else` in your main code. Where did it appear from in the comprehension?

Comment: have edited the question @Ev.Kounis i just want to create email_data2 list and the comprehension i mentioned is just an example i found

Comment: the main part i dont understand is how to apply data=ApplyFilters() before checking if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
[(x_1, data) for x_1, data in map(lambda x: (x[1], Apply_Filters(x[0])), email_data) if len(data.split()) > 1]
```

Trying to save rows such way is a terrible idea IMO.

Comment: Trying to make this process a bit faster so thought i should give comprehension a try and your answer worked like a charm. But mind if i ask why this could be a terrible idea?

Comment: Thx, because this stands against the Zen of Python, i.e. it's ugly and unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension for `email_data2`:

```
email_data2 = [(y, Apply_Filters(x)) for x, y in email_data
                                        if len(Apply_Filters(x).split()) > 1]
```

The above List comprehension is **not** particularly efficient because `Apply_Filters(x)` has to be computed **twice** in every iteration.

An explicit `for` loop would be better in this case (especially if `Apply_Filters(x)` is a *high-cost* function):

```
email_data2 = []
for x, y in email_data:
    data = Apply_Filters(x)
    if len(data.split()) > 1:
        email_data2.append((y, data))
```

Comment: Unfortunately ApplyFilter() is a costly method it do many basic and advance pre-processing steps, in total this function takes upto 2 mins to complete with around 7k iterations in the explicit for loop

Comment: Then go with the `for` loop and forget the comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I find *one shot comprehension list* really hard to understand, especially when they tend to become very long. In a few weeks, it will be hard for you or someone else to understand what you tried to do.

Not sure if you can do that as a one shot however, but maybe you could give a try to the `map` function (apply a function to all the terms of a list), then filter properly the result with `filter` and `partial`.

Say `list1` is your initial list:

```
from functools import partial
from operator import is_not

def f1(x):
  data = Apply_Filters(x[0])
  if len(data.split()) > 1:
    return tuple([x[1], data])

# so it will give you in one line
list(filter(partial(is_not, None), list(map(f1, list1)))

# in several steps
list2 = list(map(f1, list1)) # you apply f1 function to all elements of list1. Pb: you get a few None object in list2 (because you did not specify what to do if the `if` condition is not valid
list3 = list(filter(partial(is_not, None), list2)) # so, you remove the None elements from your list
```

If really your aim is to define lists on the fly with one line only, this should do the trick if you defined `f1` at first of course!